# How to add a slash to string in php before json_encode?

Tags: php, json, string-concatenation

I want to add a slash to a string in php to make it a part of a url.

Here is the code:

```
$arr = array( ..., "imagePath"=>"folderName/".$rs["imageName"] );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

expected result:

```
"imagePath":"folderName/imageXYZ.jpg"
```

observed result:

```
"imagePath":"folderName\/imageXYZ.jpg"
```

I googled it but could not find the reason. Any help is higly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *Hm,* most bizarre. Try something like `"imagePath"=>"folderName" . "/" .$rs["imageName"]` see if that works. Might have something to do with your webservice/framework.

Comment: Where do you get that observed result from?  I suspect that you are creating the string correctly, but whatever is printing it out is encoding the slash in some way.

Comment: Tried that already. Same thing.

Comment: then see the answer below. It was upvoted.

Comment: `str_replace` maybe?

Comment: or escaping it `"imagePath"=>"folderName\/".$rs["imageName"]` or `"imagePath"=>'folderName/'.$rs["imageName"]`

Comment: I use json_encode on that string. Would that make a difference??

Comment: Use stripslashes on the result before you use it

Comment: whats your `$rs["imageName"]` output?

Comment: @Andrew: imageXYZ.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the [PHP Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`:

```
"imagePath"=> sprintf("folderName%s%s", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $rs["imageName"])
```

If you continue to experience issues, keep track of what happens to the value between you setting it and you observing it's escaped value. It may be running through something that filters it/escapes it.

For example, if you are passing through json_encode, see [the option JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Now I get the following with your changes: "imagePath":"folderName:imageXYZ.jpg" i.e. instead of '/' I get ':'.

Comment: Apologies, I used the wrong one. There is a constant called DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, that's the one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It actually adds the slash to the url, which is then modified by json_encode.

Comment: Okay, one more edit with an option to the json_encode call.